# Dailog box with timer

Tags: typescript, timer, dialog, electron, messagebox

I want to create a message dialog box with 30 seconds count down along with a message how to do that in typescript, count down should be like 30 29 28 .... 0 then this message box should disappear automatically

```
dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
                        type: "info",
                        defaultId: 0,
                        title: "Timer.",
                        message: `you will be redirect to another screen in +count down+`
                    })
```

like this
[image]

Comment: You mean to have an  open dialog dynamically update? I've never seen any mention of that functionality. Seems like something you would have to build yourself using `BrowserWindow`, `modal` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like creating a countdown function with setInterval and pass this

`dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
   type: "info",
   defaultId: 0,
   title: "Timer.",
   message:`you will be redirect to another screen in +count down+
  `})`

dialog function as callback to that countdown function

```
const countdown = function(counter){

   const timer = setInterval(() => {
   counter--;
   console.log(counter);
   if(counter === 0) {
     console.log("its up");
     dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
          type: "info",
          defaultId: 0,
          title: "Timer.",
          message:you will be redirect to another screen in +counter+
      });
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
   },1000)

  }
```

Comment: yep tried but no luck:( it doesn't show a dialog box

Comment: it will enter the dialog box once it reaches to 0, but i want to display the count down seconds at the place of counter inside the dialog box.